# Spring boot + MySQL Docker compose

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect spring boot service to MySQL db, both are containers. My Docker compose is as below

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql_DB
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: delivery
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/mysql1:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
     - dev-network
  prioritization-service:
    image: sh/prioritization-service:1.0
    ports:
      - "9085:8085"
    depends_on: # Start the depends_on first
      - mysql
    environment:
      DB_USER_NAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: sh123
      PORT: 8085
      SPRING_DATA_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/delivery?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      ACTIVE_PROFILE: development,data
    networks:
      - dev-network

networks:
  dev-network:
```

Spring service not able to connect to mysql

```
: prioritization-service-pool - hikari - - Exception during pool initialization.
ticket-service-new-prioritization-service-1  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
ticket-service-new-prioritization-service-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
ticket-service-new-prioritization-service-1  |  at
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is there any network configuration below? It looks like empty configuration

Comment: driver : bridge, still not working

Comment: Try to use default network